# Foreground color for AppBarButton

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1

I have application with RequestedTheme = "Light" and DarkBlue BottomAppBar.

[image]

I would like to have white AppBarButton on the BottomAppBar:

```
<AppBArButton Foreground="White" Label="Back" Icon="Previous" />
```

But I have black circle and black label yet.  How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way is to set the `RequestedTheme` on the `AppBarButton`

```
<AppBarButton Icon="Previous" Label="Back" RequestedTheme="Light" />
```

or for more control you will need to edit the Template. Note the `Ellipse` where you can manually change the colours

```
<Style x:Key="AppBarButtonStyle1" TargetType="AppBarButton">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="AppBarButton">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="Transparent" Width="100">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="FullSize"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="60"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundEllipse">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="OutlineEllipse">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundEllipse">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="OutlineEllipse">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,14,0,13" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="40" Margin="0,0,0,5" Width="40">
                                <Ellipse x:Name="BackgroundEllipse" Fill="{ThemeResource AppBarItemBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="40" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="40"/>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="OutlineEllipse" Height="40" Stroke="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}" StrokeThickness="2" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="40"/>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="TextLabel" Foreground="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}" Width="88"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```